# react native Redux:Even though I have used useDispatch I still do not have access to methods in the action

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I've used dispatch in my component like following but I get the error modifySeatMap is not defined .But I do have modifySeatMap function defined in one of my action files. Why is this showing modifySeatMap not defined yet?
const dispatch = useDispatch();

```
  const changeStatus=(seat)=>{
    console.log("change status called with seat",seat)
    seat.status="selected"
dispatch(
  modifySeatMap(props.seatMap))
  }
```

I'm attaching the screenshot of the directory structre and the method inside the action here
[image]

Why is modifySeatMap undefined here?

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I do not see any issues.

I expect the issue is in how you apply your middleware.

It should look something like this.

```
export default store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))
```